# Get output of terminal command using Java

Tags: java, terminal, runtime

For some terminal commands, they repeatedly output. For example, for something that's generating a file, it may output the percent that it is complete.

I know how to call terminal commands in Java using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntim().exec("command goes here");
```

but that doesn't give me a live feed of the current output of the command. How can I do this so that I can do a `System.out.println()` every 100 milliseconds, for example, to see what the most recent output of the process was.

Comment: Of course, it allows access to STDOUT and STDERR. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Thanks for that. So, can you show an example of how to use this to get the output every 100 milliseconds or so?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Comment: Required reading for anyone using Runtime.exec() http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to read `InputStream` from the process, here is an example:

**Edit** I modified the code as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream) to receive the `errStream` with the `stdInput`

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("command goes here");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

For debugging purpose, you can read the input as bytes instead of using `readLine` just in case that the process does not terminate messages with `newLine`

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to freeze at in.readLine() (it doesn't output anything, but doesn't end the while loop)

Comment: Maybe the command you're running doesn't output any \r or \n characters (which would signal the BufferedReader that it has read a complete line)? Maybe it doesn't generate any output in certain terminal modes (try piping the result to 'more' and see what it outputs)? Maybe the command writes its output to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: It will freeze waiting for input, so either your processes does not terminate the data with `newline` or it does not write to the `stdout` at all

Comment: @dnault see the code I posted here for details of the Java code I tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915290/best-way-to-call-terminal-command-repeatedly#comment20924963_14915290

Comment: @CodeGuy Try exec'ing mencoder directly. Also, specify the command as a String[] instead of a single String (in case any of the arguments contain spaces).

Comment: @dnault then I get: Cannot run program "mencoder -ss 0 -endpos 60 /Users/MyFolder/MyVideo.avi -oac copy -ovc copy -o /Users/MyFolder/output.avi": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: is /Users/MyFolder/output.avi the absolute path or the relative from the pwd?

Comment: @CodeGuy you may need to specify the full path to the mencoder executable.

Comment: i have tried this but using bufferedreader we actually dont get the terminal text line by line(realtime terminal text),it copies the whole text obtained after executing the terminal command and displays it in one step,any one has any idea how to get realtime text character by character from inputstream?