# Read console output of new Terminal window

Tags: java, macos, shell, console-application

In Java, I want to run a script in the separate terminal window, on the Mac Os X:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal script.sh")`

How can I get the output of this script?

Comment: What about http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Execute_an_external_program_and_capture_the_output or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915319/get-output-of-terminal-command-using-java?

Comment: Will not work with a new terminal window.

Comment: Why do you need to open a Terminal?

Comment: It is required. In a few words - the user should be able to see what is happening, and he should have an ability to close the execution. Or maybe stop/rerun. And my program should process several situations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following way to read the outout of the command, the `result` string will have the output

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
       output.append(line);
}
inputStream.close();
process.waitFor();
String result = output.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it will not work. New Terminal window will start a new process

Answer (score 0):

Using a `BufferedReader` seems to be an easy approach.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

. . .

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal script.sh");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

// perhaps retrieve all the lines as a stream for future processing
// i.e. map, filter, reduce, etc.
Stream<String> lines = input.lines();

// or go line by line from the BufferedReader
String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
  // do something with line
}

// To just retrieve all the output as a single String
String output = input.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

. . .

input.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, but in the buffer reader, you will have an output of another process. ```open -a Terminal``` will open a new terminal window and I don't know how to handle it's output